# how can you expose ports when kicking off a docker from slurm?

Tags: docker, remote-debugging, slurm, vscode-remote

I'm trying to remotely debug code from within a docker container via VSCode.
Here's the setup:

1. ssh into a HPC cluster managed with Slurm
2. kick off a Slurm job via `srun` (see full `srun` command at the end)
3. this job fires up a docker container via the `--container-image` flag

Ultimately, I'd like be able to map a port of the host to port 22 so that I can edit my `~/.ssh/config` file and access the docker container within VSCode. I've swarmed the web in quest of instructions but I haven't found anything, so I'm coming here for help!

NB: here's the `srun` command I'm using

```
srun \
  --ntasks=1 \
  --gpus=1 \
  --cpus-per-task=4 \
  --time=6-00:00:00 \
  --container-image=<docker_image> \
  --pty bash
```